# Mysql query to select repeated data if status is same discard if status is different

Tags: mysql

Select those record if delivery_staus=2 and if master_id repeat and all master id has delivery_staus=2.

```
I try this 

      select delivery_staus, master_id from My_G 
    where delivery_staus=2 group by master_id 
    HAVING(COUNT(master_id) > 1 and delivery_staus=2)
```

but this select only repeated data

This is my table My_G with record

```
 id, master_id, firstname, lastname, email, delivery_staus
 '1',    ' 1',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '2',    ' 3',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '3',    ' 2',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '4',    ' 3',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '5',    ' 3',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  1 '
 '6',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '7',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '8',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
 '9',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
' 10',   ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  2 '
' 10',   ' 5',    ' d',    ' d',    ' d', '  1 '


Expected Output 

id,  master_id, firstname, lastname, email, delivery_staus
 '1',    ' 1',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
 '3',    ' 2',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
 '6',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
 '7',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
 '8',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
 '9',    ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
' 10',   ' 4',    ' d',    ' d',     ' d', '      2 '
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us sample data *and* expected results (it is unclear which of the two is the data that you showed).

Comment: Hello i edit question please see once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.delivery_status = 2
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.master_id = t.master_id and t1.delivery_status <> t.delivery_status
    )
```

This phrases as: get the records that have `delivery_status = 2` and for which no other record exists with the same `master_id` and a different `delivery_status`.

You can also express this with a `left join` antipattern:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 
    on  t1.master_id = t.master_id 
    and t1.delivery_status <> t.delivery_status
where t.delivery_status = 2 and t1.master_id is null
```

Comment: Unknown column t.delivery_status in where clause

Comment: Yes it looks like you have `delivery_staus`, without, not delivery_sta**t**us.